# Using python spectral package?

Tags: python, remote-sensing, python-2.7, matplotlib

I found this [tutorial](http://www.spectralpython.net/) about spectral using python and I will test `kmeans` classification using Landsat image.
I don't understand some things about this [tutorial](http://www.spectralpython.net/algorithms.html).
First thing I can't understand is about `pylab`, how to import class names dynamic in `plot` like class 1, class 2, class 3,... for any class create the kmeans algorithm?

first time to use python spectral.

can help me somone ?

here the simple code of manual :

```
from spectral import *
from pylab import figure, axes, pie, title, show
img = open_image('LT.lan').load()
(m, c) = kmeans(img, 10, 80)
import pylab
pylab.figure()
pylab.hold(9)
for i in range(c.shape[0]):
    pylab.plot(c[i])
pylab.show()
```

Comment: @Luke, mgri, BERA, ahmadhanb, lynxlynxlynx I have update